# Is it acceptable to put a video of a bug in my post to illustrate it?

Tags: discussion

A few days ago I asked the question [*Buildings flashing during the day in Watch Dogs*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/404518/screen-flashing-during-the-day-in-watch-dogs), and perhaps I already found the problem, I was thinking about ***how other users with the same problem will know that it is the problem***?

I mean, It's hard to understand exactly what it is just with the description, mostly in games made by *Bugsoft* that have high amount of bugs.

So, it's acceptable to put a video of the bug in the question? If it is, how the best way to do it?

Comment: You might want to add trigger warnings: ***WARNING - EPILEPSY RISK*** - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denn%C5%8D_Senshi_Porygon

Comment: @Valorum Thank you very much! I really hadn't thought of that, I added the notice to the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I do think it's a great way to show your problem; an image is worth a thousand words, and a video is even better.

But, your question itself must still be a good one. And should be passable even without use of the video (in case that in the future, the video gets deleted from youtube or something)

Same goes for video in answers.

A good example: [Is the tower game shown in the 'Hero Wars' ad a real game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/382544/is-the-tower-game-shown-in-the-hero-wars-ad-a-real-game/382553#382553)
The video adds to the answer, but if it would be removed the answer still works as it is.

Comment: Is it possible to host videos or other files below SE like images are currently hosted? Because "link rot" over time might indeed be a concern otherwise. Maybe we should encourage some screen shots in combination with the video?

Comment: @Amarth Maybe a *GIF* can be used instead of a video when possible, SE can host *GIF's* the same way it does with images.

Comment: @DiegoBorba GIFs are problematic for other reasons though, since they are very distracting. A link to a GIF should be ok I suppose.

Comment: @Amarth You can't host videos (MP4, GIFV, and the like) on SE's Imgur instance. SE's Imgur instance only allows JPG, PNG, and GIF.

Comment: Personally I would just dump the video on youtube. You need to start the video, and you can go forward/backwards at will without having to wait for the loop

Comment: @DiegoBorba if you insert a YouTube link on a post, it will render a thumbnail and you can play the video from the post as well. It works quite well. The only issue with videos is they potentially get taken down, deleted, etc as time goes on, hence why an adequate description should also be included in a post that uses a video to display something

Comment: @TimmyJim YouTube videos can also be set to 'Unlisted', so the only way to find/visit them is with the link. Could be useful for some people who only want the video to be viewed in the context of their post here.